# Why does WebResponse from web page have trailing space?

Tags: php, .net, webrequest, streamreader, webresponse

I have written a `PHP` page on a web site to respond with `OK`.  In `PHP`, this has been done with:

```
echo 'OK';
```

When I request the page in `.NET` and read the response into a string, the resulting string has a trailing space, so it is `'OK '`.  The length of the string is 3 chars.  Why is this the case, and how can I fix it?

The `.NET` code is:

```
Private Function GetStrFromPostRequest(ByVal url As String, ByVal encoding As Text.Encoding, ByVal params As String) As String

    Dim strWebResponse As String
    Dim Request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
    Request.Method = "POST"
    Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(Request.GetRequestStream(), encoding)
        writer.Write(params)
    End Using
    Using Response As WebResponse = Request.GetResponse
        Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream(), encoding)
            strWebResponse = reader.ReadToEnd
        End Using
    End Using

    Return strWebResponse

End Function
```

Comment: may be space exist before `<?php` or after `?>`

Comment: Specifically, a newline after `?>` is a common culprit. You can simply remove `?>` from the source file to immunize against this (PHP will process the code just fine even if the end tag is missing).

Comment: There was one after `?>`. Isn't it a bit silly that it would do that?

Comment: Nope, not silly, that makes sense in a strict way: remember that php is an embedded language. It has to leave the embedding text untouched at all times!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `PHP` source to this:

```
<?php echo 'OK';
```

That should remove the space. Any PHP file that ends with PHP code shouldn't have a closing `?>`, because it just causes annoying problems.